# Find the api call for getting the bitcoin price on Robinhood

Tags: python, api, http, post, request

I am interested in writing a python algorithmic trading bot for cryptocurrencies on [Robinhood](https://www.robinhood.com/). Currently, I have been playing around with [this wrapper](https://github.com/Jamonek/Robinhood), but it is not yet updated for cryptocurrencies. If I want to fetch the price of google stock, going to https://api.robinhood.com/quotes/GOOG/ shows the result, but I can't figure out the equivalent for say, bitcoin.

I have tried sniffing packets from my android phone to see what the app uses for its updates to the the value, but I think I am too inexperienced to figure it out that way. How can I use the python request module to find the value?

Comment: It might not available yet. Did you check [faq](https://support.robinhood.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000088623-Crypto-Availability) and [crypto](https://crypto.robinhood.com) ?

Comment: Ya, those do not have any references to the api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this repo](https://github.com/wang-ye/robinhood-crypto) can be useful to you. Robinhood recently opened the web version, and you can easily find the different API calls from Chrome Developer tools. Anyway, this repo already gets most of the endpoints for you. Sample code:

```
from robinhood_crypto_api import Robinhood
# user and password are your Robinhood login credentials
r = Robinhood(user, password)
# Current BTC quotes.
quote_info = r.quotes()
# Market order to buy/sell BTC
market_order_info = r.trade(
    'BTCUSD',
    price=round(float(quote_info['mark_price']) * 1.005, 2),
    quantity="0.00005",
    side="buy",
    time_in_force="gtc",
    type="market"
)
```